# Can I change the color mode on which an Alpha channel value is read?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop, when I use the eye dropper to read a value on an alpha channel on a RGB, 8 bit per channel file, the value is read in a 0%-100% scale, regardless it is, in reality, a 0-255 range grayscale image.

This scale is in both, the Inspector and the color panel.

[image]

I can change the color window model to tone cube or brightness cube, but that is totally useless to read the values of a grayscale image...

[image]

The RGB slider is blocked. (Yes guys, you will practice your Spanish language skills)

[image]

**Is there a way to read it on a 0-255 color range?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your info panel is showing grayscale and CMYK values. Photoshop shows 8-bit<sup>*</sup> grayscale, opacity and CMYK values in percentages.

If you switch it to show RGB values (hit the eyedropper icon), it will show you the correct 0–255 range 8-bit values... If the image is grayscale (or your viewing a channel; which is essentially the same thing) all the values will be the same, so that works just as well.

[image]

Similarly with the color sliders, you can switch to the RGB sliders which will give you a 0–255 range (just set each slider to the same values again).

---

<sup>*</sup> Interestingly, Photoshop shows the correct 16 or 32-bit opacity and grayscale values, it's only 8-bit values that show as percentages...

[image]

Comment: Oh. Changing to RGB on the left Info panel do the job, but I can not change the color slider, the RGB option is blocked :o( I will add that to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's wise to be measuring any pixel values of an *RGB* source in *CMYK* values, but somebody could correct me on that.

There doesn't appear to be any way to get 8-bit alpha values as a value between 0 and 255. I'm afraid you'll need to do some maths to get a value in a range that suits you. For 0-255 you could do:

```
PERCENTAGE * 255 / 100
```

---

#### Edit:

I'd originally answered this question mistaking that you were confusing the **k** value completely for an alpha value, rather than seeing you'd isolated your alpha channel and were taking independent samples from it. I've updated the answer to reflect this but thought a paragraph I removed may still be of use to some on this topic. Particularly if you want the alpha value of a pixel when you're not using an actual alpha channel:

> You can get an alpha value in the same palette if you use the dropdown
>   triangle in the **info** panel and change the *mode* to *opacity* in
>   the **panel options** of any of the dropdowns.